# How can I achieve GTP header compression?

Tags: c, networking

I am working for GTP header compression, I have search enough but not able to get details for GTP header compression.
Any one have details how to achieve same? I required to do header compression for the GTP packet.

Any one have details how to achieve same? I required to do header compression for the GTP packet.